# Indexing in SQL between two tuples, AND condition

Tags: sql

Can I index two tuples in SQL?

For example, if I want to check an AND condition between the same indices of two tuples:

```
Tuple 1: ('10086','10087','10932')  
Tuple 2: ('TAR','REN','RHN')
```

I would like this or be equivalent to:

```
('10086' AND 'TAR')
OR
('10087' AND 'REN')
OR
('10932' AND 'RHN')
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can, but (IIRC) MySQL cannot use an index in this situation

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use:

```
where (x, y) in (('10086', 'TAR'), ('10087', 'REN'), ('10932', 'RHN'))
```

Both MySQL and Oracle support this syntax.